# ASP.NET Dynamic Data - Back Button

Tags: filter, viewstate, asp.net-dynamic-data

I used .Net's dynamic data entity to implement a website that sits on top of my db (see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.aspx)

In the List.aspx-View for a table, I am able to sort/filter the data of the gridview. After having clicked on a row's 'Details' link, I would like to provide the user a 'Back' button in the Details-View that navigates the user back to exactly the same filtered/sorted table.

So far, all sorting and filtering information is lost when navigating back to List.aspx.

Any ideas how to implement this feature? Do I need to work with ViewState?

Thanks a lot

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my article here 
[AJAX History in a Dynamic Data Website](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/02/ajax-history-in-dynamic-data-website.html) this works when using the back button in the browser to navigate back to the List page.